# Setting the value of an HTML textbox using Javascript inside of a PHP block (using echo)

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to run a MySQL query depending on what HTML selectbox option is selected and then take the query result and output it to an HTML textbox but to no avail. I'm using the switch statement with the superglobal $_GET. I'm trying to set the value of an HTML textbox using Javascript inside of a PHP block (using echo), but it's not working. The textbox is not being populated (still blank). Could this be because the PHP is running before the textbox is getting initialized or is there something else I'm missing? I know for sure that the DB login info is correct, and the query actually works. The code is below.

```
<?php
---db login info here---

switch($_GET['string'])
{
    case "another string":
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT field1 FROM table1 WHERE id = '1'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
        break;
}

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "document.getElementById('textbox').value = '$row[0]'";
echo "</script>";   
?>
```

Comment: why are you outputting javascript in order to update an input value that php can handle without js involved?

Comment: yea...what Jakub said...why not populate the input value directly with PHP?

Comment: I am new to PHP, so I'm not sure how to populate the input value directly with PHP.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: fwiw (going with your existing technique), in order to be thoroughly helpful we should see the HTML of the input you are trying to modify (specifically, does it have `id="text box"` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple things:

1. you can verify that the PHP part is working by checking the "source" of the site when you visit it in the browser (does the `<script>` part look like you expect?)
2. Note that the "textbox" must occur earlier in the document than this script, as written
3. If the element in question is a `<textarea>`, it does not have a `value` attribute, and you need to use `innerHTML` or similar.
4. There may be bigger-picture issues with how this is being accomplished (is this ajax? all one request? why not simply author the text box with php?)

## edit, do it with PHP

If it is your code which authors the `<input>`, just do it with php in the first place (then you get the added benefit of no js dependency:

```
switch($_GET['string'])
{
    case "another string":
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT field1 FROM table1 WHERE id = '1'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
        $textboxValue = $row[0];
        break;
}
?>
// ...
<input type="text" name="foo" id="textbox" value="<?php echo $textboxValue;?>" />
```

Comment: These are all good points.  The script seems fine when looking at the "source."  The HTML textbox is initialized before this PHP script.  I'm not using a textarea.  I'm using a textbox.  I'm not using Ajax.  I'm not sure what you mean by "all one request" and "author the textbox with php."

Comment: What I mean is, do you have access to the part of your script which *does* create the input? That's clearly the right place to set it's value.

Comment: You'll probably want to use `htmlentities` on that.

Comment: I do. It's just <input id = "textbox" type = "text" readonly = "readonly">.  Are you saying to set the value here?  I'm not sure how to get the query result and set it to the value attribute here.

Comment: Yes. Just move your query block to somewhere above where you make the input. I have demonstrated in (an edit to) my answer how to do it.

Comment: I have moved the query block above where the input is.  The textbox now populates but only populates for the default case.  I have different cases tied to the different options of the selectbox.  For example, if the selectbox option selected is dog then the chosen case would be dog.  However, only the default case works for populating the textbox.  I want it to dynamically populate based on which selectbox option is selected.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well, that's growing squarely into the realm of purely-javascript (I assume you have PHP working correctly to author the `<select>`). My suggestion is to open a new SO question targeted at javascript folks more than PHP.

Comment: Here's my dilemma. I got it to work like I want using Javascript, but everything is "hardcoded."  I'm moving the data from Javascript into a database and then querying the database for what I want and then populating textboxes with database query results.  I was not sure if there was a way to do that with Javascript since the db stuff is done in PHP.  So that's why I have been asking about it from a PHP perspective.  Maybe it's something having to do with setting the value of each option or setting the ids and then using the id or value for the "case name", but neither of those worked.

Comment: It's hard to advise without knowing more about how exactly you want the interaction to be in-browser. If there is a <select> involved, I would *normally* just have PHP write all the DB rows as `<option>`s, and the jave the javascript hook on to them once the page is loaded. I'm not exactly sure where the textbox plays in, but it sounds like that will be related to an onchange event, also pure javascript. Perhaps another SO question more specifically targeted at that JS interaction, complete with HTML snippets and description of user-interaction?

Comment: What do you mean by have PHP write all the DB rows as <option>s?  Also, if I do ask another SO question do you recommend just putting the Javascript tag for the question and instead of putting HTML, PHP, and Javascript?

Comment: This question surely needs HTML tag along with the javascript tag. Regarding `<option>`s, didn't you mention a "select box"? I took that to mean `<select>` HTML element. It's tough to know what to say without seeing the relevant HTML.

Comment: I will include the same tags then. If you write all the DB rows as <option>s wouldn't you be using HTML since <select> is an HTML tag?  So it would be something like <select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

Comment: Yes, exactly like that... built with PHP based on the results of your query (if I am understanding correctly)

Comment: The thing is I already have the <select> tag and many <option> tags, but I don't see how that would tie in with PHP like you're talking about.

Comment: You said, "I have different cases tied to the different options of the selectbox". I think that's where I got confused. Is that select on the *previous* page, or are you authoring it at the same time as the <input>?

Comment: The goal is to tie the different cases to the different options, but it's currently not working as intended.  It's all authored at the same time.

Comment: Do you have a pastebin or something? I'd need to see a lot more code to be of any use.

Comment: I have removed the above paste since using Javascript and AJAX in combination with PHP solved my issue.